# Spring won't deserialize json string (unquoted property)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Spring throws an error when I send json array. I am not sure what I am missing here.

**RequestBody**

```
{
"deliverySessionId":"c1fb327b-98a8-46d4-9e82-ce7507b5be93",
imageNames: ["name1", "name2"]
}
```

**Endpoint**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/examImages/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST } )
public @ResponseBody ImageResponseCommand streamExamImages( @RequestBody ImageResponseCommand imageResponseCommand ) {
```

**Error**

```
 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

It works fine if my request doesn't contain imageNames property.

```
  { "deliverySessionId":"c1fb327b-98a8-46d4-9e82-ce7507b5be93" }
```

Comment: Try putting `imageNames` in quotes like `"imageNames": [...]`

Comment: Thankyou, I can mark it as an answer if you want to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON string isn't formatted properly. Object key's need to be wrapped in quotes.

```
{
    "deliverySessionId":"c1fb327b-98a8-46d4-9e82-ce7507b5be93",
    "imageNames": ["name1", "name2"]
}
```

Comment: Also, would like to point out that you can easily validate this using one of the many online validators, like JSONLint: http://jsonlint.com/